# How do I make my widget not overflow and extend downwards for long chat messages?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How do I limit these chat bubbles to a max certain width (about middle of the screen) and also make long messages extend downwards, i.e. wrap text?

The chat message:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel est quis dolor dignissim imperdiet at eget dui. Sed tincidunt hendrerit condimentum. Morbi et porttitor nisi. Vestibulum consectetur justo sem, quis rhoncus urna cursus sed. Etiam molestie tellus in tincidunt aliquam. Aliquam mattis scelerisque sapien, nec lobortis ante vehicula placerat. Aliquam in elit pulvinar, pulvinar elit non, interdum enim. Vivamus eu placerat nisl. In vitae nunc vel mi vehicula dictum et vel erat. Nunc pharetra tincidunt felis eu egestas. Sed tincidunt, ligula ut sodales auctor, libero arcu gravida eros, id semper est sem sit amet lorem. Pellentesque eleifend sit amet ligula non tempor. Integer a elit nec dolor ultrices dapibus vitae eget metus. Sed nec ornare leo, sed efficitur sapien. Mauris eros neque, suscipit a mattis vitae, porttitor eget lacus.

**The code:**

```
return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(flex: 10,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(timestamp),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 10, maxWidth: 200, minHeight: 15, maxHeight: 200),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(66, 135, 245, 100.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(text),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
```

**Picture of the problem (ignore the "Hello World!" message):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap the message text with Flexible or Expanded widget, like this:

```
return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(flex: 10,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(timestamp),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 10, maxWidth: 200, minHeight: 15, maxHeight: 200),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(66, 135, 245, 100.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(text),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
```